# stl unordered_set how to set initial bucket count

Tags: c++, c, unordered-map, bucket, unordered-set

For an unordered_map i set the initial bucket count by this:

```
unordered_map<string, dictionaryWord> dictionary(17749); // set initial bucket count to 17749
```

This way does not seem to work for unordered_set.

```
/*line 150*/ unsigned char mask;
/*line 151*/ unordered_set<QueryID> query_id(109); // set initial bucket count to 109
```

Compiler error =
1) expected identifier before numeric constant.
2) expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant.
And goes on with a bunch of errors

How to do the same thing for an unordered_set?

Thank you.

=================================================

There are no errors if i remove "(109)"

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'
rm -f -r build/Release
rm -f dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/acm_test
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'


CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 80ms)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/acm_test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'
mkdir -p build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/ref_impl
rm -f build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/ref_impl/core.o.d
g++ -pthread -O3 -std=c++11   -c -O2 -pthread -O3 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/ref_impl/core.o.d -o build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/ref_impl/core.o ref_impl/core.cpp
ref_impl/core.cpp:151:37: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
ref_impl/core.cpp:151:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
ref_impl/core.cpp: In function ‘ErrorCode StartQuery(QueryID, const char*, MatchType, unsigned int)’:
ref_impl/core.cpp:250:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
ref_impl/core.cpp:250:38: error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token
ref_impl/core.cpp:250:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘query_id’
ref_impl/core.cpp:257:19: error: ‘query.SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp: In function ‘ErrorCode EndQuery(QueryID)’:
ref_impl/core.cpp:265:44: error: ‘queries.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<SameQueries, std::allocator<SameQueries> >(((std::vector<SameQueries>::size_type)i)).SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp:265:58: error: unable to deduce ‘const auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
ref_impl/core.cpp:266:38: error: ‘queries.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<SameQueries, std::allocator<SameQueries> >(((std::vector<SameQueries>::size_type)i)).SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp:267:32: error: ‘queries.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<SameQueries, std::allocator<SameQueries> >(((std::vector<SameQueries>::size_type)i)).SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp:268:36: error: ‘queries.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<SameQueries, std::allocator<SameQueries> >(((std::vector<SameQueries>::size_type)i)).SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp: In function ‘void* TaskCode(void*)’:
ref_impl/core.cpp:463:41: error: ‘quer.SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
ref_impl/core.cpp:463:48: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
ref_impl/core.cpp:463:70: error: ‘quer.SameQueries::query_id’ does not have class type
make[2]: *** [build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/ref_impl/core.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/petros/NetBeansProjects/ACM_test'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: That should work: `explicit unordered_set( size_type bucket_count = /*implementation-defined*/,
                        const Hash& hash = Hash(),
                        const KeyEqual& equal = KeyEqual(),
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Comment: may we see those "bunch of errors" ?

Comment: @scones You are not worthy!

Comment: damn, but i try hard! :/

Comment: @chris and how do i set the name of the set? (wid) and what it holds (WID)?

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis It looks fine to me. Like scones asked, can you show us the actual errors? All of them.

Comment: Have you defined a specialization of `std::hash` for `WID`?

Comment: Yes, try it with a built-in type and then move to `WID`.

Comment: Did you `#include <unordered_set>`?

Comment: I just added the compiler output. wid was a simplification. Now you have the original line. Programm runs fine. I now want to set some initial bucket counts in all unordered_maps and unordered_sets to avoid bucket growths during execution

Comment: I believe you may have to show the real code. There's likely some header you're not importing, e.g. the one that contains the definition of your `QueryID` type

Comment: It must know the type QueryID because if i remove the (109) it works. And it is using this type earlier in the file so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was inside a struct.** It should have been:

```
unordered_set<QueryID> query_id = unordered_set<QueryID>(109);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the bucket count is a red herring. It looks like `QueryID` is not visible.

Comment: If this is the case, why it works fine if i remove (109). It knows the type QueryID

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis: If it works when you remove the `109` and make no other changes, I withdraw my suggestion.

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis: It would help others to help you if you included an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). Otherwise there's too many unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `QueryID` has no standard constructor ie `QueryID::QueryID() { std::cout << "foo!" };` so the unordered set does not know how to prefill with empty QueryIDs.

Try adding one.

Or you can use the second parameter to set default data to be used for every prebuilt bucket.

Reference: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set